# brighten a colour in hex with a method using rgb to hsb conversion

Tags: java, colors

I'm trying to create a method for my Minecraft mod to brighten text without changing the hue.

```
public static int renderColorToHSB(int color, float saturation, float brightness) {

    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    float r = (color >> 16 & 255) / 255.0F;
    float g = (color >> 8 & 255) / 255.0F;
    float b = (color & 255) / 255.0F;
    Color.RGBtoHSB((int) r, (int) g, (int) b, hsv);
    return Color.getHSBColor(hsv[0], saturation, brightness).hashCode();
}
```

and use
`renderColorToHSB(0xffffffff, #, #)` 0xffffffff being any colour, # is the stautation and brightness

But it doesn't seem to do what I want. Some colours are sort of how I expect them to look, but some others are just red, even though the input colour is blue or green for example.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you calling `hashCode()` instead of `getRGB()`?

Comment: Also, why are you doing these calculations to separate out the red, green, and blue channels when `Color` will do that for you?

Comment: One more: why are you dividing the rgb values by `255.0F` to convert them to floats when `Color.RGBtoHSV` takes `int` red, green, and blue components? This is almost certainly giving you wrong results.

Comment: sorry, this was done with some help, and im not fully understanding the conversions, too many numbers for me to comprehend, so if its wrong then that makes sense. i used hashCode() as some other code i was basing this off was using it, im working with hex rather than rgb and it looked like the correct thing to use.

Comment: No worries, those were just things that I didn't get when reading your question. Basically, you could represent the redness as an integer from 0 to 255, or as a fraction from 0 to 1, and it seems like these two concepts are getting mixed up in the code you have. Take a look at my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
public static int renderColorToHSB(int color, float saturation, float brightness) {
    Color c = new Color(color);
    float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), null);
    return Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], saturation, brightness);
}
```

Convert the RGB color to a `Color` object in order to get the red, green, and blue channels, use them to get the color as HSB, and then use the hue along with the specified saturation and brightness to get the ARGB color.

Note: the return value is ARGB so it will be something like `0xffcc6633`. If you want just RGB without the alpha channel, mask it with `0xffffff` like so:

```
return Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], saturation, brightness) & 0xffffff;
```

If you want to leave the saturation alone if it is very low (or completely desaturated), you could do something like this:

```
    float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), null);
    if (hsb[1] < 0.1f) {
        saturation = hsb[1];
    }
    return Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], saturation, brightness);
```

Comment: oh yes, that is much better, it does appear to be doing what i want now. though except for anything that is a shade of grey, which turns red.
https://i.imgur.com/ckuRCyo.png
https://i.imgur.com/gGKYWYn.png

Comment: @Xemnes I think the problem there is that black, grey, and white are completely desaturated, but you are turning up the saturation to whatever is passed in for the `saturation` parameter. I would suggest either using `hsb[1]` (i.e., keeping the saturation unchanged), or an `if` statement where you check if the saturation in the `hsb` array is zero and if so, leave it alone, otherwise replace it with the value from the parameter.

Comment: i think the latter would work better, i am changing the saturation to get the desired outcome for the text colour and setting brightness to 1, only problem is, im unsure how to do what you suggested really

Comment: i tried this 
```java
    public static int renderColorToHSB(int color, float saturation, float brightness) {
        Color c = new Color(color);
        float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), null);
        if (hsb[1] == 0.0f) {
            return Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], 0.0f, brightness);
        }
        else {
            return Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], saturation, brightness);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok so upon further investigation, i dont want brightness to be max on every colour. some are a lot darker colours, so i need brightness to only be added to

Comment: right so its a little messy but i believe what ive done is almost perfect to what i want https://pastebin.com/Khj3bjcN